# MVC pass value from modal to parent on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do you pass a value from a modal with rendered partial view inside to the parent textboxfor.

textbox from my parent:

```
@Html.Label("Taxpayer Name")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.taxpayername, new { @id = "search",data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal", data_backdrop = "static",data_keyboard = "false" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.taxpayername)
```

modal with the partial view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @{Html.RenderAction("Payer", "Registration");}

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Partial View:

```
<table class="table" id="payer">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("TITLE")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("NAME")
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userTitle)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName) 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.userId)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Registration",new { id=item.userId, name=item.FullName });"  onclick="SetName();">Select</a>
    </td>
</tr>
}</tbody>
 </table>

 @section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#payer").DataTable({

        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetName() {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("search");
        txtName.value = document.getElementById('name').value;
    }
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

whenever i click the select, i was able to retrieve the fullname and id but doesn't populate the textboxfor.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `SetName()` getting fired?

Comment: somthing like this @{Html.RenderAction("Payer", "Registration", new { model = Model });}????

Comment: yes sr. SetName is getting fired but doesn't populate the textboxfor

Comment: Is it executing `txtName.value = document.getElementById('name').value;` line of code??

Comment: no. nothing happens with that line.

Answer (score 0):

Move this function to parent and remove the onclick function:

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed){
      var val=$('#name').val();
      $('#search').val(val);
 }
 window.close();
});
```

Comment: tried what you said, unluckily still the same output. still called at the url but not populating the textboxfor